# Using haskell in atom - ghc mod error

Tags: haskell, atom-editor

I have installed Haskell minimal installer on Windows 10. I have been using haskell by writiting small programs in Notepad++ and running then by ghci using ':l myfile.hs'

I have now installed the hackable 'ATOM' text editor and installed the atom-haskell core packages.

However, I get the error below

```
Haskell-ghc-mod: ghc-mod failed to launch. It is probably missing or misconfigured. ENOENT
Error was: Error
spawn ghc-mod ENOENT
Debug information:
{
  "dir": "C:\\Users\\myfunnyusrname\\Desktop",
  "err": {
    "code": "ENOENT",
    "errno": "ENOENT",
    "syscall": "spawn ghc-mod",
    "path": "ghc-mod",
    "spawnargs": [
      "version"
    ],
    "cmd": "ghc-mod version"
  },
  "opts": {
    "cwd": "C:\\Users\\myfunnyusrname\\Desktop",
    "env": {
      "Path": "C:\\Program Files\\Haskell\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Haskell Platform\\8.0.2-a\\lib\\extralibs\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Haskell Platform\\8.0.2-a\\bin;C:\\ProgramData\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath;C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_121;C:\\Program Files\\Haskell Platform\\8.0.2-a\\mingw\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\;C:\\Ruby24-x64\\bin;C:\\Users\\myfunnyusrname\\Anaconda3;C:\\Users\\myfunnyusrname\\Anaconda3\\Scripts;C:\\Users\\myfunnyusrname\\Anaconda3\\Library\\bin;C:\\Users\\myfunnyusrname\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;C:\\Users\\myfunnyusrname\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm",
      "PATH": "C:\\Program Files\\Haskell\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Haskell Platform\\8.0.2-a\\lib\\extralibs\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Haskell Platform\\8.0.2-a\\bin;C:\\ProgramData\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath;C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_121;C:\\Program Files\\Haskell Platform\\8.0.2-a\\mingw\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\;C:\\Ruby24-x64\\bin;C:\\Users\\myfunnyusrname\\Anaconda3;C:\\Users\\myfunnyusrname\\Anaconda3\\Scripts;C:\\Users\\myfunnyusrname\\Anaconda3\\Library\\bin;C:\\Users\\myfunnyusrname\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;C:\\Users\\myfunnyusrname\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"
    },
    "encoding": "utf8",
    "maxBuffer": null
  }
}
Environment (filtered):
{
  "Path": "C:\\Program Files\\Haskell\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Haskell Platform\\8.0.2-a\\lib\\extralibs\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Haskell Platform\\8.0.2-a\\bin;C:\\ProgramData\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath;C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_121;C:\\Program Files\\Haskell Platform\\8.0.2-a\\mingw\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\;C:\\Ruby24-x64\\bin;C:\\Users\\myfunnyusrname\\Anaconda3;C:\\Users\\myfunnyusrname\\Anaconda3\\Scripts;C:\\Users\\myfunnyusrname\\Anaconda3\\Library\\bin;C:\\Users\\myfunnyusrname\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;C:\\Users\\myfunnyusrname\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"
}
Show Stack Trace
```

I understand that i am missing something BUT I do not know anything about PATH and variables.

If someone could please help me, I would be grateful to you

Note: I am using WINDOWS 10 laptop

### Edit:

I have now installed ghc-mod (thanks to @Mark Seemann). But when i try 'ghc-mod' from gitbash I get:

```
K@ORUKO-PC MINGW64 ~
$ ghc-mod
bash: ghc-mod: command not found
```

Comment: You need to make sure that Windows can find `ghc-mod`, so you need to put it in your `PATH`. See e.g. https://superuser.com/q/284342/12455 for more information.

Comment: So how do I find out that where did it install ghc-mod ?

Comment: Search your hard drive.

Comment: thanks @MarkSeemann... it is working now :-) :-)

Comment: In order to find where stack installed `ghc-mod` you can do `stack exec where ghc-mod` from Bash, right where you have your `stack.yaml` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting Haskell to work on Windows 10 in Atom is doable, but it does require a bit of fidgeting before you can get it to work.

## ghc-mod

IIRC, *ghc-mod* isn't part of the GHC installation, so the first step you most likely need to take is to add it.

### Cabal

If you're only using GHC (and not Stack), you can [install it using Cabal](http://www.mew.org/~kazu/proj/ghc-mod/en/install.html):

```
$ cabal install ghc-mod
```

### Stack

If you're just getting started with Haskell, then you probably want to stick with Cabal, but once you've gotten the hang of it and need to do slightly more complicated work, you should consider using [Stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org) instead.

I usually have fairly good success with running

```
$ stack build ghc-mod
```

in my Stack project directory, but the Atom editor project has more detailed guidance here: https://github.com/atom-haskell/haskell-ghc-mod/wiki/Using-with-stack

Comment: hi thanks for answering . when i run cabal install ghc-mod I get this [output](https://pastebin.com/Wj1zyEQW)

Comment: @Jhoy See the error message at line 122. I've always only executed Haskell code and tool chain from Git Bash, which uses MINGW. That seems to circumvent that problem.

Comment: Awesome thanks that installed using git bash. What to next to get rid of the error?

Comment: @Jhoy Are you still getting the same error as in the OP?

Comment: @Jhoy Can you run `ghc-mod` from the command-line (Git Bash)? From an arbitrary directory? When I do that, I get a response that I haven't supplied enough arguments to the program, but at least it tells me that Windows can find the executable (`ghc-mod.exe`).

Comment: Keep in mind that if you change the resolver in the `stack.yaml` file you must redo `stack build ghc-mod` in order to build the appropriate version of ghc-mod against the resolver you're using.